# Can not get laravel cookie laravel_token while consuming own API

Tags: laravel, api, cookies, vuejs2, laravel-passport

**Cookie is avaiable in browser but can not get it even can not check if it exists .**
[image]

working on laravel and vuejs app where I am using passport for authentication.
I am [consuming own api with vuejs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript) so I have added **CreateFreshApiToken** middleware in kernel.php

vuejs is creating and sending laravel_token cookie successfully but I can not read it using vuejs or javascript.

since I can not check if cookie is available or not I can not check if user is logged in or not.

How I will tell vuejs that user is logged in and take to intended route ?

For now I am saving access_token in **localStorage** and sending it with each request but I am looking for a solution which can help to use laravel builtin **laravel_token** cookie to authenticate and authorize the users.

**More Details**

If i run this command in console then I get response

```
document.cookie.match('XSRF-TOKEN')
```

But

```
document.cookie.match('laravel_token')
```

returns null

I think the tick icon in the shown image at top is sign of making it private or something that makes it inaccessible.

**Update**

I found something from internet
[image]
But I still want to know how I can tell vuejs app that user is logged in or not ??

**Update 2**

For now I am sending access_token in header manually from vuejs and it is working fine.

```
if(localStorage.getItem('laravel_token') !== 'undefined' &&  !! localStorage.getItem('laravel_token') == true){

    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer '+ localStorage.getItem('laravel_token')
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: laravel_token cookie is http only that means we can not get it from js.

Answer (score 0):

A little work around will be for you to implement the authenticated method in your LoginController, and return a json success code. You can then receive this code and store.

```
public function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    // return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    return json_encode(['authenticated' => true]);
}
```

Using axios...

```
axios.post('/login', {
    email: user.username,
    password: user.password
}).then(response => {
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response)
        //response.data.authenticated will return true if user has been authenticated 
    })
}).catch(err => {
   console.log(err)
})
```